# Diferença quando utilizando um objeto e um array sendo passados como o this no apply utilizando a função concat

Tags: javascript, array, característica-linguagem

Estou estudando JavaScript e me deparei com essa diferença quando utilizando um objeto e um array sendo passados como o `this` no `apply` utilizando a função `concat`. No primeiro caso utilizo o próprio `this` como objeto, no segundo caso utilizei um array vazio, e a diferença é que ele parece estar concatenando o objeto com o array que foi passado como argumento na função, diferente de quando eu passo apenas um array vazio.

Qual seria o motivo dessa diferença?

Exemplo 01:

```
const test = Array.prototype.concat.apply(this, [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [1, 2, 3, 4]
]);
console.log(test);
```

Saída do exemplo 01:

```
[{}, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Exemplo 02:

```
const test = Array.prototype.concat.apply(
  [],
  [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
  ]
);
console.log(test);
```

Saída do exemplo 02:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 4):

## Conceitos iniciais

Antes de tudo, é importante saber diferenciar dois conceitos que são de suma importância para a compreensão do porquê os seus dois exemplos acima se comportam de modo diferente.

Apesar destas duas ideias terem uma relação muito grande com o `this` (são, no fundo, quase a mesma coisa, só que em duas situações diferentes), é importante saber diferenciá-las:

#### Palavra-chave `this`

A *[palavra-chave `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)*, de modo muito resumido, irá recuperar o ***valor*** (geralmente um objeto) do contexto em que está sendo executado. No escopo global, o `this` irá se referir ao objeto `window` (ou `global`, em Node.js).

Portanto, no seu primeiro exemplo, onde você faz:

```
//                     Palavra-chave this
//                            ↓↓↓↓
Array.prototype.concat.apply( this , [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [1, 2, 3, 4]
]);
```

Você está utilizando a *palavra-chave `this`* para recuperar o *valor* do contexto em que está sendo executada (no caso será o objeto `window`, já que está no escopo global) e passar como ***valor `this`*** para o método `concat`.

#### Valor `this`

O *valor `this`* (geralmente um objeto) é recuperado dentro de um contexto (como o escopo global ou escopo de funções) pela *palavra-chave `this`* – já mencionada anteriormente. Veja um exemplo:

```js
const person = {
  name: 'Foo',
  greet: function() {
    // Estamos usando a -  para obter
    // o   relativo ao método `greet`.
    //           ↓↓↓↓
    const name = this.name;
    console.log(`Olá, eu sou o ${this.name}!`);
  }
};

person.greet(); // Olá, eu sou o Foo!

// Estamos modificando o   que o método `greet`
// recuperará ao utilizar a - . 
person.greet.apply({ name: 'Luiz' }); // Olá, eu sou o Luiz!
```

Conforme você pode ter percebido acima, é muito fácil de confundir esses dois conceitos, já que eles são tão próximos. Mas, em suma, veja o *valor `this`* como aquilo que é retornado pela *palavra-chave `this`*.

Além disso, como você pode ter visto, o *valor do `this`* é facilmente modificável com a utilização de métodos de uma função como o [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) ou [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Todos esses três métodos do `Function.prototype` usam o primeiro argumento para modificar o ***valor*** que a ***palavra-chave `this`*** recuperará quando for chamada. Esse argumento é geralmente chamado de argumento *thisArg*.

## A resposta de fato

Como qualquer objeto, arrays também [têm métodos](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods_of_Array_instances), como o próprio `concat`. Esses métodos esperam operar sobre algum array. Na implementação desses métodos, esse array será obtido através do *valor* que será retornado pela *palavra-chave `this`*.

A própria especificação da linguagem evidencia que o *valor `this`* é usado para isso. Se você está curioso, veja o primeiro passo da [especificação do `Array.prototype.concat`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.concat).

Sabendo disso, é válido dizer que o método `concat` (assim como os outros métodos do `Array.prototype`) esperam operar sobre um array. No entanto, quando esse não é o caso, algumas coisas estranhas, porém previsíveis, acontecem.

No caso do `concat`, é sabido que um novo array é criado, e os primeiros elementos desse novo array são ocupados pelos elementos do array do *valor `this`*. Se esse valor não for um array, ele simplesmente ocupará a primeira opção desse array que foi criado.

#### Primeiro exemplo

Portanto, no seu **primeiro exemplo**, através do método [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), você está modificando o *valor `this`* que o método `concat` irá operar. Assim, ao invés de operar com um array, será usado o objeto que você o passou no argumento *thisArg* do `apply` – no caso, esse objeto é `window`, já que você utilizou a *palavra-chave `this`* no escopo global (que recupera `window` ou `global`, no Node.js).

Vamos ver um exemplo mais simples:

```js
const person = { name: 'Bob' };

const arr = Array.prototype.concat.apply(person, [2, 3]);

console.log(arr);
console.log(arr[0].name); // Bob
console.log(arr[1], arr[2]); // 2 3
```

Note que o valor que passamos como `this` (através do `apply`) ocupou a primeira posição do array criado e retornado pelo `concat`.

#### Segundo exemplo

No segundo exemplo, como um array vazio será o *valor `this`* do `concat` (já que você o passou como argumento *thisArg* do `apply`), nada de muito inesperado, senão o comportamento comum do `concat` ocorrerá. Vamos ver:

```js
const arr1 = [].concat( 
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [1, 2, 3, 4]
);

// É o mesmo que isto:

const arr2 = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [1, 2, 3, 4]
]);

// Ou até o mesmo que isto:

const arr3 = Array.prototype.concat.call(
  [],
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [1, 2, 3, 4]
);

console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
console.log(arr3);
```

Isso tudo é uma confusão causada pelo método [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) e o `this` em JavaScript, que pode assumir vários significados dependendo do contexto. Procure saber mais como eles funcionam.